# PHP Header not redirecting from Form Submit action page

Tags: php, html, forms

On submitting form, user is taken to following action page. On this page email is sent along with attachment.

I am receiving email and attachment but `header('Location: ...')` is not working. Action page is not redirecting and keeps on showing loading sign in broweser. On debugging found no errors on page.

*This problem only comes when a file is attached.

PHP form processing page:-

```
<?php
require_once 'settings.php';
if (( isset($_POST)) && ( empty($_POST))) {
    header('Location: ../career.html');
    die ;
}

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    if (empty($value)) {
        header('Location: ../career.html#error');
        die ;
    }

    if (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    $val[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($value)));
}

$tmp = date('r');
$message = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>";
$message .= "<p><strong>Name: </strong>{$val['name']}</p>";
$message .= "<p><strong>Email: </strong>{$val['email']}</p>";
$message .= "<p><strong>Phone: </strong>{$val['phone']}</p>";
$message .= "<p><strong>Work Experience: </strong>{$val['workex']}</p>";
$message .= "<p><strong>Career: </strong>{$val['career']}</p><br>";
$message .= "<p> <i> This form was submited from {$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]} on $tmp by IP {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} </i> </p>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$header = "From: " . $val['name'] . " <" . $val['email'] . ">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: " . $val['name'] . " <" . $val['email'] . ">\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $uid . "\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";

$header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message . "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";

if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {

    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > $fileSize) {
        header('Location: ../career.html?#error-size');
        die ;
    }
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (!in_array($ext, $fileType)) {
        header('Location: ../career.html?#error-type');
        die ;
    }

    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])));
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content . "\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--" . $uid . "--";

}

if (mail($mailTo, $careerSubject, $message, $header)) {
    header('Location: ../career.html#success');
    die ;
} else {
    header('Location: ../career.html?#error');
    die ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Do redirect headers work in any of your other pages, or do they behave the same?  Have you tried using an absolute path?

Comment: There is some issue with File Upload Headers i doubt. When a file is not attached it work!!

Comment: may be it just `die ;` try with `exit();`

Comment: No, I thought that too @Shehary but I tested it and `die;` does not prevent the redirect.

Comment: my guess, you are checking file size without uploading the file, i don't see any code where upload is done before checking file size and you just trying to check the file size on the fly and there are couple of unknowns and no HTML form and in your form you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Answer (score 0):

try remove "..", like  header('Location: /career.html#error');

Comment: As far as I know, this answer is incorrect. Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't the `../` specify a directory change?

Comment: may be i am wrong but it is impossible use ".." in "Header()"